# Create Pagination for database content using Bootstrap without page reload

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, pagination, jquery-pagination

I am working on a site using bootstrap. I want to create pagination for my data in discussion board via bootstrap. I tried many things but cannot find a way to page the results without refreshing the page.
I searched in the web, got a code that make a request to database each time a page number is clicked and fetch the results. But here, I am fetching all the results in database at once into a single division. I need to page the data in that division using bootstrap pagination.
Also, I am using jquery hashchange for navigation. so, I need a way to page the results that are compatible to hashchange. That means, when a page is changed url should also update.
Please somebody help me with this.

This is the view of my site.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gMSIz.png

Comment: Can anybody come up with a better solution, like a script to make pagination other than DataTables. Because, I don't want to include one more library as the size of the app is keep on increasing..

Comment: Can you use ajax? You detect the id of the button and pass to the PHP page to process and return it to refresh the div without reload the whole page.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at DataTables and try [this implemenatation](http://datatables.net/blog/Twitter_Bootstrap_2).